# Rails - if record selected show a value of related to selected record attribute(column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form for cargo which belongs to truck, in one of fields I have to assign cargo to truck by trucks number, thats the part I've done, but I cant figure out how to show trucks volume based on which truck now  chosen, I dont even know if thats possible, because cargo wont connect with truck before record submitted to server. Any ideas would be appreciated. Here's field for truck number:

```
<%=f.text_field :truck_number, class: "form-control", data: {autocomplete_source: Truck.order(:number).pluck(:number)} %>
```

I was tried a lot of silly things like this:
"div where trucks volume shows" value:

```
Truck.where("truck_id = ?", params[:truck_number]).pluck(:truck_volume).first
```

ofc none of them didnt worked out

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with ajax: make your form remotable, put in create/update action

```
truck = Truck.find(@transportation.truck_id)
@truck_chosen_volume = truck.volume
```

and

```
 respond_to do |format|
if @transportation.save
format.js
```

in create/update.js.erb select something and append to it @truck_chosen_volume variable. Wasted so many hours for this, hope someone would need this.